# Uninstalled Nokia PC Suite, now shows "language loading failed" on Windows startup

Tags: windows-7

I installed Nokia PC Suite on my laptop (Dell, Windows 7) for transferring photos from my mobile to my PC.

Unfortunately it did not work so I uninstalled Nokia PC Suite, but now when I open My Computer it shows an entry for Nokia Phone Browser. Moreover when I now open my PC it opens with the message Nokia PC Suite "Language loading failed" and only after clicking OK am I able to proceed further.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Which Nokia PC Suite did you load? Usually Nokia installations install a great deal more than 'just' the PC Suite.

The easiest solution may well be to reinstall it, check the problem is fixed and then uninstall it again.